# Using Auth0 as Authentication Provider in GAM

Tags: auth0, genexus, genexus-gam

I'm currently trying to connect using GAM with a 3rd party authentication provider that is [Auth0](https://auth0.com/es). It provides many different types of connecting with them, one of which is by using Oauth2.

I've followed [this](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39484,GAM%20Oauth%202.0%20Authentication%20Type) article in Genexus Wiki that has some examples. The configuration is very straight forward, using the information provided by Auth0 (client secret, client id, endpoints, etc) but after setting up all that, at the moment of trying to login it only shows up with the local login, instead of redirecting to Auth0 Login Page.

Has anybody configured and run succesfully with this Provider, or any other that isn't the Google/Office365 examples from the wiki?

I'm using Genexus 17 U5 with Java Generator

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not fill in the "URL" property correctly, like this image below:

[image]

We have it up & running with Office 365.
The config for Office 365 is here:

[https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39166,Office%20365%20Authentication%20using%20GAM](http://%20https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?39166,Office%20365%20Authentication%20using%20GAM)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It was solved unchecking "Include Redirect URL" in Authorization tab.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31698605)